# Controls not recognizing inside a SignIn form using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to automate Sign In functionality in www.sears.com, but could not recognize the Email text field using the below code

```
package com.bigbasket.framework.lab;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Sears {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();
        browser.get("http://www.sears.com/en_us.html");
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gnf_01_tree_item_5']/span/a")).click();
        WebElement currentElement = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myProfiles']/div"));
        Actions actions = new Actions(browser);
        actions.moveToElement(currentElement).build().perform();
        browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='subnavDD_myProfile']/ul/li[1]/p/a")).click();

        try{
            WebElement formElement = browser.findElement(By.id("loginFormDisplay"));
            currentElement = formElement.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(currentElement));
        currentElement.sendKeys("srinimarva@gmail.com");
        browser.quit();

    }

}
```

Could you please help me in resolving this? Apologize I'm an amateur in Selenium WebDriver for asking a silly question.

Comment: what is the error message you got from running this code?

Comment: @YuZhang No such element found exception.

Comment: where? which line?

Comment: need you to post your HTML code as well

Comment: Yes because the xpath which you are using is having two elements with the same xpath in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your email field is in iframe so to access it you need to switch to frame first, following is the working code for your issue :

```
        WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();
        browser.get("http://www.sears.com/en_us.html");
        browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gnf_01_tree_item_5']/span/a")).click();
        WebElement currentElement = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myProfiles']/div"));

        Actions actions = new Actions(browser);
        actions.moveToElement(currentElement).build().perform();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(browser.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='subnavDD_myProfile']/ul/li[1]/p/a"))));
        browser.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='subnavDD_myProfile']/ul/li[1]/p/a")).click();

        try{
            WebElement frameElement = browser.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[contains(@name, 'easyXDM_default')]"));
            browser.switchTo().frame(frameElement);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        browser.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("srinimarva@gmail.com");
        browser.quit();
```

Comment: Ravikar : How did you come to know that this is the frame i need to use, because there are many frame i saw in pagesource and this is somewhere at bottom of pagesource ? Can you please help..

Comment: When you inspect an element just check if the field is in any <iframe> (Generally when such login forms popup up in a page they are in frames). you can just scroll up in your page source a bit and check which iframe your elements come under.

Comment: Ohh  great.. When i use firebug , the iframes are not mentioned in the DOM. Inspect Element solves it. Thanks. :-)